# Saving an ndarray of objects in Python to file

Tags: python, arrays, json, save, pickle

I have an ndarray of objects in Python. Each of the objects is of their own class. The question is how can I store such data in the file?

Pickle complains that it cannot work with vector objects even when converting to a list. I tried also to save it in the pure text but since my data array is quite large it has truncations in the output string, so I need to use mapping. But in this case I will have an error: write() argument must be str, not map. To convert a map to the string I tried to use JSON like in the code below (x is my data I want to save):

```
import json
x_str = json.dumps(map(np.array2string(x), x))
text_file = open("testoutput.txt", "w")
text_file.write(x_str)
```

I am getting a message: Object of type map is not JSON serializable.

Comment: Why not just `text_file = open("test.txt", "a")` and then `for i in x: text_file.write(np.array2string(i))`?

Comment: Also, why not `numpy.save` & `numpy.load`? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html

Comment: And finally, the problem in your code might just be that you're not passing the function to `map` properly, try `x_str = json.dumps(map(np.array2string, x))`.